# React this.setState is not a function only on second call of the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to React and have been making a CRUD application to Create Read Update and Delete commands. While making the pop-up box, that will be used to update a specific command I encountered the bug : this.setState not a function. The bug appears only on the second call of the function ChangeUpdateObject that changes the command that is being updated in the pop-up. When opening the pop-up for the first time the correct command is selected and it's information is displayed in the pop-up.
I hope this is enough to fix the problem, but i could post more if necessary.
Here's the code for the component where the ChangeUpdateObject is situated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Commands from "./components/Commands";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import NewCommand from "./components/NewCommand";
import UpdateCommand from "./components/UpdateCommand";
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state=({
      //current command that is going to be sent to handleAddCommand
      currentCom:[],
      //CurrentCom's arguments
      currentArgs:[],
      //Output of the APICall()
      output:[],
      //Command Arguments of the Update POPUP
      UpdateArguments:[],
      //Selected Command that is being Updated in the UPDATE POPUP
      selectedUpdateObject:{},
      //Actual commands that are the responses of the command being UPDATED
      selectedUpdateResponses:[]
    });
    this.APICall=this.APICall.bind(this);
    this.changeUpdateObject=this.changeUpdateObject.bind(this);
    this.handleAddArgument=this.handleAddArgument.bind(this);
    this.handleAddUpdateArgument=this.handleAddUpdateArgument.bind(this);
    this.APICall();
  }
  APICall(){
    //Gets all commands from API
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'https://private-aa937-commandtable.apiary-mock.com/commands');

    request.setRequestHeader('x-api-version', '1');

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
        var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        this.setState({
          output:json
        });
      }
    }.bind(this);
    request.send();
  }
  handleAddCommand(command){
    //Sends the command to the API
    //needs work for formating the data to be sent
    //So the data being sent isnt the same as data in API yet, need to be changed
      let fullCommand=command;
      let currentArgs=this.state.currentArgs;
      delete currentArgs.id;
      fullCommand.Arguments=currentArgs;
      fullCommand= JSON.stringify(fullCommand)
      console.log(fullCommand);

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.open('POST', 'https://private-aa937-commandtable.apiary-mock.com/commands');

      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      request.setRequestHeader('x-api-version', '1.0');

      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log('Status:', this.status);
        console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
      }
      };

      var body = fullCommand;

      request.send(body);
  }
  handleAddArgument(Argument){
    //Adds an argument to the NewCommand tab
    let Arguments= this.state.currentArgs;
      Arguments.push(Argument);
    this.setState({currentArgs:Arguments});
  }
  handleAddUpdateArgument(Argument){
    let Arguments= this.state.UpdateArguments;
    //console.log("this is Argument :" + Argument +". This is Arguments :"+Argument.Name);
    Arguments.push(Argument);
    console.log(Arguments);
    this.setState({
      UpdateArguments:[]
    });
  }
  handleDeleteArgument(id){
    //Deletes an argument in the New Command Tab
    let Arguments= this.state.currentArgs;
    let index= Arguments.findIndex(x=> x.Id===id)
    Arguments.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({currentArgs:Arguments});
  }
  handleDeleteUpdateArgument(id){
    //Deletes an argument in the Update POPUP
    let Arguments= this.state.UpdateArguments;
    let index= Arguments.findIndex(x=> x.Id===id)
    Arguments.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({UpdateArguments:Arguments});
  }
  handleUpArgument(id){
    //Increases the position in the Arguments component in the New Command Tab
    console.log("tried to up");
    let Arguments=this.state.currentArgs;
    let index=Arguments.findIndex(x=>x.Id==id);

    if(index>0){
    let placeholder1=Arguments[index-1];
    let placeholder2=Arguments[index];
    Arguments[index]=placeholder1;
    Arguments[index-1]=placeholder2
    this.setState({
      currentArgs:Arguments
    })
    }
  }
  handleUpUpdateArgument(id){
    //Increases the position in the Arguments component of the Update POPup
    console.log("tried to up");
    let Arguments=this.state.UpdateArguments;
    let index=Arguments.findIndex(x=>x.Id==id);

    if(index>0){
    let placeholder1=Arguments[index-1];
    let placeholder2=Arguments[index];
    Arguments[index]=placeholder1;
    Arguments[index-1]=placeholder2
    this.setState({
      UpdateArguments:Arguments
    })
    }
  }
  handleDownArgument(id){
    // Decreases position of an argument in the Arguments component of the New Command tab
    let Arguments=this.state.currentArgs;
    let index=Arguments.findIndex(x=>x.Id==id);
    if(index<(Arguments.length-1)){
    let placeholder1=Arguments[index+1];
    let placeholder2=Arguments[index];
    Arguments[index]=placeholder1;
    Arguments[index+1]=placeholder2
    this.setState({
      currentArgs:Arguments
    })
    }
  }
  handleDownUpdateArgument(id){
    // Decreases position of an argument in the Arguments component of the Update POPUP
    let Arguments=this.state.UpdateArguments;
    let index=Arguments.findIndex(x=>x.Id==id);
    if(index<(Arguments.length-1)){
    let placeholder1=Arguments[index+1];
    let placeholder2=Arguments[index];
    Arguments[index]=placeholder1;
    Arguments[index+1]=placeholder2
    this.setState({
      UpdateArguments:Arguments
    })
    }
  }
  changeUpdateObject(id){
    //Changes the Command that is being updated in the Update popup
    let UpdateObject=this.state.output[id-1];
    this.setState({
      selectedUpdateObject:UpdateObject
    },()=>{
      console.log("I think it updated it");
      this.show("UpdateCommand");
    });
  }
  SendResponses(Response,Arguments){
    //Sends the commands that are used as responses for the command being UPDATED in the Updtate POPUP
    //Also sends the arguments to the UPDATE POPUP so they can be displayed, seems to not be working.
    console.log(Arguments);
    this.setState=({
      selectedUpdateResponses:Response,
      UpdateArguments:Arguments
    });
  }
  show(id){
    //Shows the Update POPUP
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <UpdateCommand input={this.state.output}
      Arguments={this.state.UpdateArguments}
      Command={this.state.selectedUpdateObject}
      addCommand={this.handleAddCommand.bind(this)}
      addArgument={this.handleAddUpdateArgument.bind(this)}
      deleteArgument={this.handleDeleteUpdateArgument.bind(this)}
      upPosition={this.handleUpUpdateArgument.bind(this)}
      downPosition={this.handleDownUpdateArgument.bind(this)}
      Responses={this.state.selectedUpdateResponses}
       />
      <Header/>
      <NewCommand input={this.state.output} Arguments={this.state.currentArgs}
      addCommand={this.handleAddCommand.bind(this)}
      addArgument={this.handleAddArgument} deleteArgument={this.handleDeleteArgument.bind(this)}
      upPosition={this.handleUpArgument.bind(this)} downPosition={this.handleDownArgument.bind(this)}

      />
      <Commands input={this.state.output}
      SelectUpdateObject={this.changeUpdateObject.bind(this)}
      SendResponses={this.SendResponses.bind(this)}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're binding in both `constructor` and `render`?

Comment: @OrB No there isn't except to make sure that i have binded this to the function. Just something i tried to fix the bug and left it in after it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're overriding `setState` method in `SendResponses` method instead of calling it. You basically assign object to it which is, for sure, something you didn't intend to do. That's why your second call doesn't do what's expected.
Change:

```
this.setState=({
  selectedUpdateResponses:Response,
  UpdateArguments:Arguments
});
```

to:

```
this.setState({
  selectedUpdateResponses:Response,
  UpdateArguments:Arguments
});
```